# MVVM BindingAdapters not showing ProgressBar

Tags: android, mvvm, android-architecture-components

I'm trying to create a simple example with databinding and BindingAdapters in order to show/hide a ProgressBar depending on TextView if it's empty or not. Below you can see my code. What I'm doing wrong?

`loading_state.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="textString"
            type="String"/>
    </data>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:visibleGone="@{textString==null}">
        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{textString}"/>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

My BindingAdapter

```
object BindingAdapters {
    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter("visibleGone")
    fun showHide(view: View, visible: Boolean){
        view.visibility = if (visible) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    }
}
```

I include the layout in my second fragment in order to check the textview text

```
<include layout="@layout/loading_state"
    app:textString="@{textView2.text.toString()}"/>
```

and also in my SecondFramgent class I take the value from MainFragment class (I'm using the new Navigation component)

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    val txtFromMain = SecondFragmentArgs.fromBundle(arguments)
    textView2.text = txtFromMain.txtFromMain
}
```

What am I missing?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those facing the same issue you can find my solutions matches in my case below:

I had to change my BindingAdapter.

```
@BindingAdapter("visibleGone")
fun showHide(view: View, visible: String){
    view.visibility = if (visible.isEmpty()) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not set two-way databinding for TV, thus string is not getting updated inside databinding

```
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{textString}"/>
```

Change `android:text="@{textString}"` to `android:text="@={textString}"`

This is first look of the problem, does it help?

Comment: The `loading_state.xml` it's just for the ProgressBar. I don't want to update the textView inside of it. I have a `TextView` inside my `second_fragment.xml` which id is `textView2` and it's getting the value via Navigation arguments passing from `MainFragment.kt`.

Comment: So when the app starts it does hide the view?

Comment: If the view is hidden on startup, but nothing changes when the value of string is changed -> databinding is working, but view is not getting notified when string changed, try use ObservableField<String> instead of String

Comment: ProgressBar not showing. I want the progressbar to be showing only if the textview from second fragment is null or empty. Here is my repo [link](https://bitbucket.org/panos_mir/gitservicefork/src/develop/)

Comment: Where exactly should I put ObservableField<String>? For simplicity I have static text. `findNavController().navigate(
                        MainFragmentDirections.showText("text from main fragment")
                )` this is how i statically pass the value to second fragment.